# Error No Module named "PyMySQL" Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql

i have problem to try pymysql.

1. my computer is using windows 10
2. use python 3.5
3. i have installed pymysql via `pip install pymsql` and success, no error. i have checked with `pip list` and get `PyMySQL (0.7.9)`

but when i run `import PyMySQL` get error no module named "PyMySQL" where is the problem?

edited :

but if i try `import pymysql`, i got error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                 
  File "pymysql1.py", line 1, in <module>                                                                                          
    import pymysql                                                                                                                 
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>                            
    from .err import (                                                                                                             
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 1, in <module>                                  
    import struct                                                                                                                  
  File "C:\python\struct.py", line 2, in <module>                                                                                  
    pack('hhl', 1, 2, 3)                                                                                                           
NameError: name 'pack' is not defined
```

Answer (score 11):

step-1 :Uninstall the existing pymysql by using the command

```
pip uninstall PyMySQL
```

step-2 : Install the pymysql by using the command pip3

```
pip3 install PyMySQL
```

step-3: `import  pymysql`

This should work. I am using python3.4 in windows 8 when I tried to import pymysql using the command `import PyMySQL` it didn't work, but after performing the above steps then I tried `import pymysql`  then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

The name of the import doesn't need to be the same as the project. Use:

```
import pymysql
```

See:
https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/example.py

Also, you can't use any python if I understand correctly. The requirements posted
https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL#installation:

> Requirements Python -- one of the following:
> CPython >= 2.6 or >= 3.3
>
> PyPy >= 4.0
>
> IronPython 2.7
> MySQL Server -- one of the following:
> MySQL> >= 4.1 (tested with only 5.5~)
> MariaDB >= 5.1

Comment: i have tried and get error many lines and the end eror : name 'pack' is not defined

Comment: Please edit your question saying your tried this, and post the errors, in their entirety.

Answer (score 0):

If even sudo apt-get install python3-pymysql or pip3 install pymysql does not work for you then go to PyMySQL page.https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL, download the zip file,extract it, cd to that location and type python setup.py install.
This worked like a charm for me.