# PyMySQL ModuleNotFound Error Python 3.6.4

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pycharm, connector, pymysql

I'm on a Windows 10 machine trying to use PyMySQL from PyCharm with Python 3.6.4.

I've installed PyMySQL with pip install PyMySQL, and it was successful.

However, the line import pymysql gives me a ModuleNotFoundError (exit code 1)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280762/error-no-module-named-pymysql-windows-10) recommends uninstalling and then reinstalling with pip3, but that hasn't made a difference for me.

What else could I try?

Comment: Can you check your pycharm interpreter (settings => search(interpreter)) to see if, under the module list, there is PyMySQL? I suspect 1. that pycharm has not updated the current interpreter, which is unlikely, or 2. that you're using a different interpreter for your current pycharm project as the one that pip installed PyMySQL to.

Comment: Yes, only pip and setuptools are listed.

Comment: How would I find the correct place to install PyMySQL to?

Comment: Are there other interpreters in the list in Pycharm? If there isn't, you can click the gear button to the immediate right of the box, and select add local. Navigate to the python.exe where pip is installing (probably by default) to, and add it from there.

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much!